# SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL) isn't working as expected

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am making a pong clone in C++/SDL2. To take keyboard input from multiple keys, I would like to use SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL) with a Uint8. However, it isn't working as expected.

Expected behavior: pong paddles move up and down with each keypress.

Actual behavior: keys are not registered.

Here is my code (note that variables written in uppercase letters are from `variables.h`):

```
// g++ main.cpp `pkg-config sdl2 SDL2_ttf --cflags --libs`
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <iostream> // For io
#include <time.h>   // Rand seeder

const bool debug = true;

// Basic stuff needed for SDL2
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

const int WINDOW_CENTER_X = WINDOW_WIDTH / 2;
const int WINDOW_CENTER_Y = WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2;

const char* WINDOW_TITLE = "Pong";

// Define the location of the paddles in the bitmap
const int PADDLE_BITMAP_X = 0;
const int PADDLE_BITMAP_Y = 0;

const int BALL_BITMAP_X = 100;
const int BALL_BITMAP_Y = 0;

// Positions of player 1 and player 2
const int PADDLE1_X = 50;
const int PADDLE2_X = WINDOW_WIDTH - 75;

// Paddle width and height
const int PADDLE_WIDTH = 20;
const int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;

// Speed of both players
const int PLAYER_SPEED = 0;

// Ball Speed -- this will not be constant
// The Ball Modifier will modify the speed based on the place it lands on the paddle
// Ball speed will never go under 10, and will accelerate over time
// Ball diameter
const int BALL_SPEED = 100;
const int BALL_MODIFIER = 5;
const int BALL_DIAMETER = 10;

const int BALL_CENTER_X = WINDOW_CENTER_X - BALL_DIAMETER;
const int BALL_CENTER_Y = WINDOW_CENTER_Y - BALL_DIAMETER;

const int LANG = 3;
const int LANG_ENGLISH = 3;
const int LANG_GERMAN = 4;

// Game Entity data structure
struct GameObject
{
    SDL_Rect ScreenLocation;
    SDL_Rect BitmapLocation;

    int SpeedX;
    int SpeedY;
};

// SDL stuff
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gWindowRenderer;
SDL_Rect gScreen;
SDL_Event e;

// Game objects
GameObject gPlayer1; // Paddle 1
GameObject gPlayer2; // Paddle 2
GameObject gBall;    // Ball

// Scores. I feel like it's better to leave them uninitialized.
int gPlayer1Score;
int gPlayer2Score;

void Render();

bool init();

bool GameQuit;

void Quit();

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // const Uint8* keyStates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    if( init() == false )
    {
        std::cout << "Init failed. Bye bye!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    while( !GameQuit )
    {
        const Uint8* keyStates = SDL_GetKeyboardState( NULL );
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) )
        {
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                GameQuit = true;
            if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
            {
                switch( e.key.keysym.scancode )
                {
                case SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE:
                    GameQuit = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if( keyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_UP ] )
        {
            gPlayer1.ScreenLocation.y -= PLAYER_SPEED;
        }

        if( keyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN ] )
        {
            gPlayer1.ScreenLocation.y += PLAYER_SPEED;
        }

        if( keyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_W ] )
        {
            gPlayer2.ScreenLocation.y -= PLAYER_SPEED;
        }

        if( keyStates[ SDL_SCANCODE_S ] )
        {
            gPlayer2.ScreenLocation.y += PLAYER_SPEED;
        }

        Render();
    }
    Quit();
    return 0;
}

bool init()
{
    bool success = true;

    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO < 0 ) )
    {
        success = false;
        return success;
    }

    if( TTF_Init() < 0 )
    {
        success = false;
        return success;
    }
    srand( time( NULL ) ); // Seed rng

    // From SDL_Rect.h
    // 64 typedef struct SDL_Rect
    // 65 {
    // 66  int x, y;
    // 67  int w, h;
    // 68 } SDL_Rect;
    GameQuit = false;

    gPlayer1.ScreenLocation.y = ( ( WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 ) - ( PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2 ) );
    gPlayer1.ScreenLocation.x = PADDLE1_X;
    gPlayer1.ScreenLocation.w = PADDLE_WIDTH;
    gPlayer1.ScreenLocation.h = PADDLE_HEIGHT;

    gPlayer2.ScreenLocation.y = ( ( WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 ) - ( PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2 ) );
    gPlayer2.ScreenLocation.x = PADDLE2_X;
    gPlayer2.ScreenLocation.w = PADDLE_WIDTH;
    gPlayer2.ScreenLocation.h = PADDLE_HEIGHT;

    gBall.ScreenLocation.x = BALL_CENTER_X;
    gBall.ScreenLocation.y = BALL_CENTER_Y;
    gBall.ScreenLocation.w = BALL_DIAMETER;
    gBall.ScreenLocation.h = BALL_DIAMETER;

    gPlayer1.BitmapLocation.x = PADDLE_BITMAP_X;
    gPlayer1.BitmapLocation.y = PADDLE_BITMAP_Y;
    gPlayer1.BitmapLocation.w = PADDLE_WIDTH;
    gPlayer1.BitmapLocation.h = PADDLE_HEIGHT;

    gPlayer2.BitmapLocation.x = PADDLE_BITMAP_X;
    gPlayer2.BitmapLocation.y = PADDLE_BITMAP_Y;
    gPlayer2.BitmapLocation.w = PADDLE_WIDTH;
    gPlayer2.BitmapLocation.h = PADDLE_HEIGHT;

    gBall.BitmapLocation.x = BALL_BITMAP_X;
    gBall.BitmapLocation.y = BALL_BITMAP_Y;
    gBall.BitmapLocation.w = BALL_DIAMETER;
    gBall.BitmapLocation.h = BALL_DIAMETER;

    gPlayer1.SpeedY = PLAYER_SPEED;
    gPlayer1.SpeedX = 0;
    gPlayer2.SpeedY = PLAYER_SPEED;
    gPlayer2.SpeedX = 0;

    gPlayer1Score = 0;
    gPlayer2Score = 0;

    gScreen.x = 0;
    gScreen.y = 0;
    gScreen.w = WINDOW_WIDTH;
    gScreen.h = WINDOW_HEIGHT;

    // Note to self: Leave this out since color keying NULL will segfault.
    // SDL_SetColorKey(gBitmap, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(gBitmap->format, 255, 0, 255));

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
        WINDOW_TITLE,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        WINDOW_WIDTH,
        WINDOW_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED );
    // Render SDL Window
    gWindowRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( gWindow, -1, 0 );
    if( gWindowRenderer == nullptr )
    {
        success = false;
        return success;
    }
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize( gWindowRenderer, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gWindowRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF );

    return success;
}

// Display Menu Text
bool Menu()
{
    bool success = false;
    if( LANG == LANG_ENGLISH )
    {
        // DisplayText("Start (G)ame", 350, 250, 12, 255, 255, 255);
        // DisplayText("(Q)uit Game", 350, 270, 12, 255, 255, 255);
        success = true;
        return success;
    }

    else if( LANG == LANG_GERMAN )
    {
        // DisplayText("(G) Spielen", 350, 270, 12, 255, 255, 255);
        // DisplayText("(Q) Spiel verlassen", 350, 270, 12, 255, 255, 255);
        success = true;
        return success;
    }

    else
    {
        return success;
    }
}

void Render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear( gWindowRenderer );
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gWindowRenderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF );
    SDL_RenderFillRect( gWindowRenderer, &gScreen );

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gWindowRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );

    SDL_RenderFillRect( gWindowRenderer, &gPlayer1.ScreenLocation );

    SDL_RenderFillRect( gWindowRenderer, &gPlayer2.ScreenLocation );

    SDL_RenderFillRect( gWindowRenderer, &gBall.ScreenLocation );

    SDL_RenderPresent( gWindowRenderer );
}

void Quit()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate a concise answer.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Builds & runs fine on my Debian 10 system, though `PLAYER_SPEED` is zero so nothing useful happens to `gPlayer1.ScreenLocation.y`/`gPlayer2.ScreenLocation.y` in the `keyStates` if-blocks.

Setting `PLAYER_SPEED` to something other than zero fixes that on my end.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was my problem or not, since I'm not using any kind of source control. But, in any case, this fixed the problem for me, so I'm flagging it as an answer.